# I don't think BeautifulSoup is scraping a website properly

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website to gain text from a jam-packed website. I was expecting to see a text including:
`'<text vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" style="fill: rgb(230, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2; font-size: 160px; line-height: normal;">529,093</text>'`
but I instead received a blank list: `'[]'`

I used this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b  
from urllib.request import urlopen  
url='https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6'  
html=urlopen(url)  
sp=b(html, 'lxml')  
sp.findAll('a')
```

Please tell me if this is a duplicate, which it probably is, though I have not seen a question that looks like so. [This may be a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568529/beautifulsoup-does-not-read-full-html-obtained-by-requests)

Comment: the page is dynamic. there are no `<a>` tags in the initial html

Comment: @chitown88 how can I find a, well, non-dynamic version?

Comment: You could see if the data is acquired through api/XHR. Or you could use selenium to render the data and then pull the html. What data are you after exactly?